# Are socket.io messages enrypted

Tags: node.js, encryption, websocket, socket.io

I'm using NodeJs with socket.io. I just want to know if the socket.io communicates using clearText or it does some kind of encryption. I mean is it safe to send some private user data over these sockets ?
If they are encrypted, what is the encryption protocol ?
I know that these socket are built over TCP, will they become secured if I'm using Https ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Socket IO connections with  `https` or `wss` are secured as long as you have valid SSL in your server

```js
const socket = io('https://example.com'); // or wss://
```